# Sending a meeting request from .Net c# code to outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I am developing web application using Asp.net MVC , in my business layer in the application , i want to create a function that sends a meeting request from c# code to outlook email address calendar.

I mean i want the c# code to act as the a sender, is sending a meeting request from its email address.

is there are any recommendations for libraries or 3rd parties components. or what is the best way to achieve that

i am using this code

```
 string startTime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            string endTime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(endTime).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("");

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            msg.From = new MailAddress(mailfrom, "W-LOA Application service");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailto));
            msg.Subject = Subject;
            msg.Body = emailbody;

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");

            //PRODID: identifier for the product that created the Calendar object
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Win-LOA //Outlook MIMEDIR//EN");
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");

            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", startTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("BeginTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", endTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("EndTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("LOCATION: {0}", "Location"));

            // UID should be unique.
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));

            str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
            str.AppendLine("ACTION:Accept");
            str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
            str.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY");
            str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
            ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
            ct.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");
            AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
            //Response.Write(str);
            // sc.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 2;
            sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.Send(msg);
```

And in the file App.config i am using this configuration ,

```html
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="lma@MyCompanyDomainname.com" deliveryMethod ="Network">
        <network defaultCredentials="true"   host="smtp.office365.com"  port="25"  />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

but it give me the following error

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Comment: You should look at EWS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Which SMTP Client are you using, I mean the email service provider?

Comment: In your app.config you've set `defaultCredentials="true"` and in your c# code you explicitly set `UseDefaultCredentials = false`. Is that intentional?

Comment: You can use Mailgun's API to facilitate this type of stuff. I had ran into the same issue while using in production, decided to stop using my own mail server and use Mailgun. Haven't looked back since.

Comment: @Adwaenyth no it is not intended , it is just a mistake.

Comment: @Rahul Kishore , what do u mean with Mailgun's API is it something i should replace my mail server with it ?!!

Comment: Yes. Mailgun is a service created by Rack space for sending out emails on behalf of services such as the one you I think you're trying to create. With Mailgun you basically replace your server with their server and you use their mail server to send out your emails.

Comment: @Rahul Kishore , this sound great .. could u please send me a fast thing that is equivalent to the code in the question , or at least the help of how to use it ??

Comment: Go to Mailgun's website. I would post code but I'm not at the office at the moment. It's a simple method that uses RestSharp to basically create an email fill in some details which Mailgun provides then you send it out.

Comment: @Rahul Kishore , Okay will check that , but does it support sending a meeting request to an outlook email address as this is my mail objective here .

Comment: @Rahul it is not a free tool , is not it ??

Comment: Do i need to do something in IIS to just fix the code that i had set in the question ??1!!

Comment: @Laila, it's not free but on you get to send 10k emails before being charged.

Comment: @Rahul my application is an enterprise application that supposed to send many meeting requests so i don't know if this is the perfect solution for my case